# onClick for select menu?

Tags: jquery, select, onclick

the .click() event doesn't seem to work on select, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/fMTzD/

Even before the options are shown, I need the jQuery click function to do something. Is is possible? I don't mind even if the options are not shown at all.

Thanks

Comment: It is working what it is written for.. what are you expecting ???

Comment: Just curious what browser/version you're using? Works in my versions of FF and IE but I've heard about issues with this before.

Comment: @Craig it does not work in my copy of Google Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `onFocus` instead (although `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` are suitable alternatives):

```
$("select, button").focus(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

See [my updates](http://jsfiddle.net/fMTzD/3/) to your jsfiddle.

You cannot use `onChange` as that is triggered after the user chooses an option from the dropdown.

Comment: correct, if you want to select any option from select menu, the good event for this is not `click`/`onClick`, just use `change`/`onChange`

Answer (score 0):

mouseup works too..

check here -

http://jsfiddle.net/fMTzD/4/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is wrapping the `select` in a `span` and using it's `click` event:

Markup:

```
<span id="use-this">
    <select>
    </select>
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#use-this").click(function(){
    alert("Select box was clicked");
});
```

*I'd still like to know the reason behind select click event not triggering*